# php shell_exec is not showing result

Tags: php, bash, shell, shell-exec

im trying to check   bandwidth of my server from php file

so in linux i use this command

```
iftop -t -s 1 -n -N 2>/dev/null | awk '/Total send rate:/ {print $6}'
```

this id command from which i get output example:  **149Mb**

so i try to print that in php but is not working im using

```
$output = shell_exec("iftop -t -s 1 -n -N 2>/dev/null | awk '/Total send rate:/ {print $6}'");
echo "$output";
```

so i dont get output (example  149Mb) when i visit  mypage.php

Comment: 1. Are you sure you can run the `shell_exec` function form your webserver? 2. I'm almost sure `iftop` requires `root` permission, does your webserver user have root permissions?

Comment: Tried exec ()? ....

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of $6 getting interpolated? What is the output you are getting?  Try this:

```
$output = shell_exec("iftop -t -s 1 -n -N 2>/dev/null | awk '/Total send rate:/ {print \$6}'");
```